# Rerun code if file doesn't exist is not working

Tags: python, error-handling, try-catch

I have this code to read a file

```
def collect_exp_data(file_name):
    data = dict()
    while True:
        try:
           with open(file_name, 'r') as h:
                break
                for line in h:
                batch, x, y, value = line.split(',')                            
                try: 
                    if not batch in data:
                        data[batch] = []
                    data[batch] += [(float(x), float(y), float(value))]
                except ValueError: 
                    print("\nCheck that all your values are integers!")   
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("\nThis file doesn't exist, Try again!")
    return data
```

I'm trying to add some error handling, i want to re ask the user to enter file in case the file doesn't exist, but the code is just returning an endless loop!
what did I do wrong and how can I fix it?

Edit:

If i try and take the while loop outside, then it works in case file doesn't exists, but if file exists, the code is just stopping after the loop and not running next function, here is the code

```
def collect_exp_data(file_name):
    data = dict()
    with open(file_name, 'r') as h:
        for line in h:
            batch, x, y, value = line.split(',')                           
        try: 
            if not batch in data:
                data[batch] = []
            data[batch] += [(float(x), float(y), float(value))]
        except ValueError: 
            print("\nCheck that all your values are integers!")   
    return data

while True:
    file_name = input("Choose a file: ")
    try:
        data = collect_exp_data(file_name)
        break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('This file does not exist, try again!')
```

Comment: the file name is passed as a parameter, which means that is not the job of this function to ask the user for it. You should move the loop outside the function, so the function only does what is supposed to do: collect data from a file or return an error. Post the code where you ask the user to input the filename and we will see how to do the loop there. The code is running an infinite loop because you have a `while True` on it

Comment: Post updated with new code!

Comment: Looks like you have an indentation issue in the collect_exp_data function. Your whole try/except block needs to be indented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a condition to break the loop

```
finished = False
while not finished:
    file_name = input("Choose a file: ")
    try:
        data = collect_exp_data(file_name)
        # we executed the previous line succesfully,
        # so we set finished to true to break the loop
        finished = True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('This file does not exist, try again!')
        # an exception has occurred, finished will remain false
        # and the loop will iterate again
```

Comment: Why use *finished*? Traditional pattern would be *while True* in conjunction with *break*. No need for an additional variable

Comment: that's true. the original question was how to re-ask the user for input. the additional variable would make more sense for a number of tries, as suggested by user20153225

Answer (score 0):

Do all your exception handling in the main function.

```
def collect_exp_data(filename):
    data = dict()
    with open(filename) as infile:
        for line in map(str.strip, infile):
            batch, *v = line.split(',')
            assert batch and len(v) == 3
            data.setdefault(batch, []).extend(map(float, v))
    return data

while True:
    filename = input('Choose file: ')
    try:
        print(collect_exp_data(filename))
        break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('File not found')
    except (ValueError, AssertionError):
        print('Unhandled file content')
```

Obviously the assertion won't work if debug is disabled but you get the point